# Do I need to encrypt Paypal Add to Cart buttons?

Tags: java, encryption, shopping-cart, paypal

I've been reading through some of the documentation on Paypal's site regarding the Website Payments Standard option. Unfortunately, some pages are not being found.

I know I can use the Paypal Tool for creating encrypted buttons, but these are saved on Paypal's site, and they have to be 'physically' created for each individual product you want to use them for.

I would like to have the buttons 'dynamically' generated so that information such as item_name, item_amount, etc. are values that are set based on a particular item. These values would be pulled from a database.

I know Java, but I'm no expert...and I use JSP and Java Servlets for my site. Keep in mind that I don't know how to interact with Paypal's API's yet...in fact I would like to avoid this if I could.

I found a PDF file on Paypal's site that finally showed basic coding examples for creating non encrypted buttons - thus allowing for the dynamic implementation of the button, and its hidden variables. But, there won't be any button encryption.

So now the big question is this -- Do I really need to encrypt the Add To Cart buttons?

If the answer is 'yes', why is it necessary? Also, I don't think I can figure out how to do the encryption on my own...can someone please provide some basic guidance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good tutorial on button encryption here: [Encrypted Website Payments—Java Developers](http://en.csharp-online.net/Encrypted_Website_Payments%E2%80%94Java_Developers)

Do you really need to encrypt the buttons?  I don't think you do, it's just an extra precaution.  The tutorial has some good reasons why you'd want to encrypt the contents of your buttons: [Encrypted Website Payments](http://en.csharp-online.net/Encrypted_Website_Payments)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I hope the information will help me learn more about this all in an easier fashion.

Answer (score 0):

One option is not to encrypt, but to use a hash trick to detect tampering. See the answer posted here: [How do I make a PayPal encrypted buy now button with custom fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14489512/105539) . Even though I explain it in PHP, you can easily translate that to what you're doing in Java.