# How do I make a PayPal encrypted buy now button with custom fields?

Tags: php, button, encryption, paypal

Is there a way that my PHP code can generate an encrypted BuyNow button that also includes custom fields and also implements an IPN URL and redirect page?

Comment: Thanks, Will! And if you have any other advice on asking questions in compliance with the FAQ, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to encrypt. Simply take the 'custom' variable, and, among other things you might need to put in there, add a hash of the price and product number, like so:

```
$sCustom .= '|' . md5($sSalt . $sProduct . $sPrice);
```

Then, when the IPN is processed, ensure that this hash was not disturbed with what is received back. If it was, then block the transaction.

Comment: is there any place I can find a tutorial or any help on coding the page on my server that receives the IPN and reads the received message? I'm really new at this and been trying to figure this out!

Comment: a full tutorial on this would be awesome.

Comment: this will lead to exposing all stuff you need for internal processing ... IPN address (maybe) any IDs or stuff you don't need the user to know.

Comment: it would be better to see if paypal's [Encrypted Web Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0QC0X4) buttons have any custom fields you can use

Answer (score 0):

in the encrypted buttons theres is one field called 'custom', you can serialize an array into it and it will be returned to your IPN :)